# Sony Vaio Fn Keys not working

Tags: xubuntu, vaio, function-keys

I have installed xubuntu 14.04 on an old sony vaio (vgn fs35gp model) and none of the <kbd>FN</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> keys are functioning (volume ,brightness etc).
 `Xev` doesnt give any outputs when <kbd>Fn</kbd> key is pressed. Similarly there are two special keys (<kbd>S1</kbd>,<kbd>S2</kbd>) on the laptop which doesn't give any outputs. Any advices are welcome.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In the terminal:

```
sudo leafpad /etc/default/grub
```

Change

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="
```

Then, save the file.

```
sudo update-grub
```

Restart computer.

Or if you want GUI for those changes:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install grub-customizer
```

Those changes did it for me, if it won't help you, we can examine further.

**EDIT:**

also try: `acpi_listen` in terminal...after that press some <kbd>fn</kbd> + <kbd>XY</kbd> combinations

Comment: Thanks for your reply Michal. Unfortunately it didn't work again. acpi_listen also doesn't give any outputs.   By the way I did a clean install of Xubuntu 15.04 to see if anything will change but still the same.