# ASUS X555LN Brightness fn key not working in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, grub2, nvidia, keyboard, brightness

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my ASUS X555L Laptop using an nVidia GeForce 520M Graphics card. The <kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd>/<kbd>f6</kbd> keys are unable to adjust brightness. Currently my screen brightness level is maximum.
My grub file looks like this :

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0 
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

Also I tried installing `XBacklight` but that doesn't fix this problem .

I will be highly grateful if someone could help me with this...

Comment: check my answer here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/637155/sony-vaio-fn-keys-not-working/637167#637167

Comment: So your line:  `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"` looks like: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="`

Comment: @MiHa  Thanks for your reply.. I tried what you suggested in your answer. My screen brightness faded but still the fn keys don't work in acpi_listen let me inform you that all other fn keys are working in acpi+listen .... What should I do now????? Thanks

Comment: @MiHa Grub file after changes : GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi= "
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi_backlight=vendor"

Comment: Check this answer of mine, which is more comprehensive and it includes all my steps, which I had to take and try to make Brightness work on my Asus notebook: http://askubuntu.com/questions/476664/cannot-change-backlight-brightness-ubuntu-14-04/630660#630660

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Brightness fn key shortcut doesn't work on ASUS laptop](http://askubuntu.com/questions/471847/brightness-fn-key-shortcut-doesnt-work-on-asus-laptop)

Answer (score 0):

For ASUS laptops the string must be

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi="
```

Then run `sudo update-grub`.

This will create events for Fn buttons.

Comment: Thank you very much..  I tried your solution but still not working acpi_listen would still listen only other fn keys except the brightness buttons.. I have a question Can I try editing the xorg.conf file in etc/x11 folder... Will that help???? Thanks....

Comment: It will not help if there are no key events.

Comment: well that's exactly what I've suggested in comment :)