# How can I enable brightness hotkeys for Asus ROG 752 in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 16.04, shortcut-keys, asus

The brightness hotkeys have no effect in Ubuntu 16.04. My laptop is an ASUS G752VL-DH71. I'm running proprietary graphics card drivers (after enabling, I could at least toggle brightness manually.) The graphics card is an nvidia geforce gtx 965m.

I tried the update suggested [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/642577/asus-x555ln-brightness-fn-key-not-working-in-ubuntu-14-04) without any success.

Some other hotkeys (volume) work.

Any suggestions?

Edit: now the brightness control doesn't work through system settings either, regardless of gfx driver.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but updated to kernel 4.12 and most of the problems went away. I followed the instructions suggested [here](http://linuxg.net/install-kernel-4-12-on-ubuntu/).

Don't forget to update grub after the kernel installation and before reboot with

```
sudo update-grub
```